# Spring Security Login Issue in Cloud Foundry with Domain Masking

Tags: spring-security, cloud-foundry, cloudflare

I have a problem when trying to login into the web application through Safari . Each tries will redirect me back on the login page. Logging in using Chrome and Firefox works just fine.

The issue above only occurring if I access the site through my custom domain through masking. If I use the actual domain mydomain.cfapps.io` the issues go away.

**UPDATE**

Header shown without domain masking

```
Request URL:https://mydomain.cfapps.io/admin/dashboard
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
 Origin: https://mydomain.cfapps.io
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-US
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Referer: https://mydomain.cfapps.io/login
Response Headers
 Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 15:39:28 GMT
 Transfer-Encoding: Identity
 X-Cf-Requestid: 7ea5df14-c3c9-4388-50c0-6b3ace496a91
 Connection: keep-alive
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Content-Language: en-US
 Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

and with domain masking

```
Request URL:https://mydomain.cfapps.io/admin/dashboard
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Request
 Origin: https://mydomain.cfapps.io
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-US
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Referer: https://mydomain.cfapps.io/login
Response Headers
 Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 15:44:05 GMT
 X-Cf-Requestid: cd11f2b8-6de2-4d15-7080-30ebc46cf84f
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 0
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Location: https://mydomain.cfapps.io/login
 Set-Cookie:   __VCAP_ID__=ff76fe69e56d4e329a638d5e8aa7fd7048f6dfc82bc5474882987e4dae5b66f8; Path=/; HttpOnly, JSESSIONID=D0015361361D1E013C47AF0D0D110E91; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

I spot there are few differences on the response headers. Could this be the cause ? Any idea what might cause this ?

**UPDATE2**

I am also using CloudFlare to enable SSL with my domain, thus I have the following CNAME

```
www is an alias of mydomain.com
```

I believe this issue is due to Safari restriction on cross domain cookies. However I am not sure how to fix this.